# Angular 7 - Validate input field only if checkbox is checked

Tags: angular, angular-validation

I'm using angular 7 and I have a form with two input fields, while the first one is always required, the second one should be required only if a checkbox is checked.

I'm trying to use a FormGroup with a custom validator:

```html
<form [formGroup]="exampleForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="first" formControlName="first">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]=" checked" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">Make second input field required</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="second" formControlName="second">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

```js
exampleForm: FormGroup;
checked: boolean;

ngOnInit() {
  this.exampleForm = new FormGroup({
    'second': new FormControl('', [this.validateIfChecked()]),
    'first': new FormControl('example', [Validators.required])
  });
}


validateIfChecked(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {
    [key: string]: any
  } | null => {
    if (this.checked) {
      return control.value ? null : {
        'err': true
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

The problem is that the validation is performed only when the text in the two input fields is updated, while if I check/uncheck the checkbox the state doesn't change and to force the validation I have to change the text in the second textbox.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hugk2j) you can see an example on stackblitz: if you check the checkbox, the status doesn't change.

How can can I force the validation when the checkbox status changes?

Comment: what about disabled the input? NOTE: you must disable and enable the control using exampleForm.controls.second.disable() and exampleForm.controls.second.enable(). https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d7hj6a?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use crossfield validation. Include the checkbox in your formgroup

```html
<form [formGroup]="exampleForm">
    <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="first" formControlName="first">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="checked">Make second input field required</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="second" formControlName="second">
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.exampleForm = new FormGroup({
    'second': new FormControl(''),
    'checked': new FormControl(false),
    'first': new FormControl('example')
    }, [this.validateIfChecked()]);
}


validateIfChecked(): ValidatorFn {
    return (form: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const checked = form.get('checked');
    const second= form.get('second');
    if (checked && !second) {
        return {
        'err': true
        };
    }
    return null;
    }
}
```

In this case, if 'checked' is true then 'second' is required

if in doubt https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation

Answer (score 4):

If you actually don't want to include the checkbox value to your form, you can make a separate form control, which is not included in your form. Based on the checkbox value you can clear validators or add required validator:

```ts
checked = new FormControl(false);

// ...

this.checked.valueChanges.subscribe((bool: boolean) => {
  bool ? this.exampleForm.get('second').setValidators(Validators.required) : 
         this.exampleForm.get('second').clearValidators();
  this.exampleForm.get('second').updateValueAndValidity();
});
```

And the relevant template:

```html
<mat-checkbox [formControl]="checked">Make second input field required</mat-checkbox>
```

Your forked **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-72nsho?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically add validation required to the form control based on checkbox clicked.

**Template:**

```
<form [formGroup]="exampleForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="first" formControlName="first">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checked" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" (click)="checkstate()">Make second input field required</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="second" formControlName="second">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**Component:**

```
checkstate(){
  this.checked = !this.checked;
  if(this.checked){
     this.exampleForm.get('second').setValidators(Validators.required);
  }else{
     this.exampleForm.get('second').clearValidators();
  }
  this.exampleForm.get('second').updateValueAndValidity();
}
```